# I am creating a function that takes a filtered array and outputs a TextBlock in an adaptive card with the birthdays of users(Person and date of birth)

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a function that takes a filtered array and outputs a TextBlock in an adaptive card with the birthdays of users (Person and date of birth), I wrote the code but I have an error: [onTurnError] unhandled error: Error: Payload is incorrect

this is a teamsBot file.js

```
if (invokeValue.action.verb === "event5") {
     const res = await axios.get("https://365.sharepoint.com/sites/Manage/_api/Web/Lists(guid'')/Items", {
       headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
       }
     })
         console.log(res);
         let today = new Date();
         // const tmp1 = res.data.value.filter(item => moment(item.field_4).format('MM') === moment(today).format('MM'));
         // console.log(tmp1);
         const tmp1 = res.data.value.map(val => {
           return{
             name: val.field_1,
             bdate: new Date(val.field_4)
           }
         })
         const currentMonth = (new Date()).getMonth()
         const filtredEmployees = tmp1.filter(employee => {
         return employee.bdate.getMonth() === currentMonth
         })
         console.log(filtredEmployees);
     const card = cards.card1(tmp1);
     await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] });
     return { statusCode: 200 };
   }
```

and this is cards.js

```
const card1 = (tmp1) => {
            return[
              {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                "content":{
                  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                  "version": "1.4",
                  "body": [
                    tmp1.map(item => {
                      return(
                        {
                          "type": "TextBlock",
                          "text": item.bdate,
                          "wrap": true
                        }
                      )
                    })  
                  ],
                  "actions": [
                  {
                    "type": "Action.Execute",
                    "title": "На главную",
                    "verb": "hello",
                    "fallback": "Action.Submit"
                  }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
      module.exports.cards = {
card1: card1
  }
```

Comment: Which line is the error referring to?

Comment: It outputs normally up to this line, but with debugger, and as you click further, the code breaks and writes Payload is incorrect `await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] }); `